# Back to root_menu in script doesn't respond like it should

Tags: bash, shell-script, menu

### Menu and its submenus in single file bash script with a back to root menu for each.

My issue is that the `show_root_menu` call sometimes just jump to the upper menu instead of the root.

[Bash-installer-menu](https://github.com/wingarmac/Bash-installer-menu/blob/main/Installer-menu).

It goes most often wrong with the nvidia submenu, to get back to the root menu.

Instead it goes to the "Package options" `show_pckg_menu`, when "show root menu" is selected from the "Install graphic proprietary driver"  submenu:

[image: show_root_menu]

---

[image: show_nvidia_menu]

---

[image: show_pckg_menu]

My ohter related questions resolved so far:

- [What's the difference between "sh command" and run as executable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733152/whats-the-difference-between-sh-command-and-run-as-executable/)
- [Creating & debug of a bash script menu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/733425/creating-debug-of-a-bash-script-menu)

`$ shellcheck myscript No issues detected!`

The actual script is:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
show_root_menu(){
width=72
height=50
menu_height=8
backtitle="Installer-menu"
title="Setup opions"
menu="Choose one of the following options:"

options=(1 'Add Mint PPA and update' 
         2 'Install Cinnamon '
         3 'update and upgrade '
         4 'Additional software installation '
         5 'Upgrade Kernel '
         6 'Resolve Ubuntu Cinnamon issues '
         7 'Install graphic proprietary driver'
         x reboot
         q quit )
    
result=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                --title "$title" \
                --menu "$menu" \
                $height $width $menu_height \
                "${options[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)
}
show_pckg_menu(){
width=72
height=22
menu_height=8
backtitle='Installer-menu'
title='Package options'
menu='Choose one of the following options:'

options=(1 'Install package list'
         2 'Export package list'
         3 'update and upgrade'
         4 'Show root menu'
         x reboot
         q quit )

result=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                --title "$title" \
                --menu "$menu" \
                $height $width $menu_height \
                "${options[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)
}
show_solver_menu(){
width=72
height=22
menu_height=8
backtitle='Installer-menu'
title='Resolver menu'
menu='Choose one of the following options:'

options=(1 'Network applet problem'
         2 'Sound problem'
         3 'update and upgrade'
         4 'Show root menu'
         x reboot
         q quit )


result=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                --title "$title" \
                --menu "$menu" \
                $height $width $menu_height \
                "${options[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)
}
show_nvidia_menu(){
width=72
height=22
menu_height=8
backtitle='Installer-menu'
title='NVidia driver selection'
menu='Choose one of the following options:'

options=(1 'Install nvidia 515'
         2 'Install nvidia 525'
         3 'Update and upgrade'
         4 'Show root menu'
         x reboot
         q quit )

result=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                --title "$title" \
                --menu "$menu" \
                $height $width $menu_height \
                "${options[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)
}
show_root_menu
case "$result" in
    1)  echo 'Mint backport repos installed';
        apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 A6616109451BBBF2;
        sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com vanessa main upstream import backport romeo" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list';
        sh -c 'echo "deb-src http://packages.linuxmint.com vanessa main upstream import backport romeo" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list';
        apt-key export 451BBBF2 | gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mint.gpg;
        apt update;
        show_root_menu;;
    2)  echo 'Installation of Cinnamon';
        apt install slick-greeter muffin cinnamon;
        show_root_menu;;
    3)  echo 'Package upgrade';
        apt update && apt upgrade -y;
        show_root_menu;;
    4)  show_pckg_menu;;
    5)  sh ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh;
        show_root_menu;;
    6)  show_solver_menu;;
    7)  show_nvidia_menu;;
    x)  echo Reboot;
        reboot;;
    q)  clear; 
        exit ;;
esac

show_pckg_menu
case "$result" in
     1) echo 'Package Install';
        sh installpkgs.sh;;
     2) echo 'Manualy installed packages exported';
        sh pkgsexport.sh;;
     3) echo 'Package upgrade';
        apt update && apt upgrade -y;
        show_pckg_menu;;
     4) show_root_menu;;
     x) echo 'Reboot';
        reboot;;
     q) clear; 
        exit ;;
esac

show_solver_menu
case "$result" in
     1) echo 'Applying changes to network settings';
        clear;
        option_picked "Option 1 Picked";
        touch /etc/network/interfaces;
        sh -c 'echo "auto lo" >> /etc/network/interfaces';
        sh -c 'echo "iface lo inet loopback" >> /etc/network/interfaces';
        sh -c 'echo "  renderer: NetworkManager" >> /etc/netplan/*.yaml';
        netplan apply;
        show_solver_menu;;
     2) echo 'Applying changes to sound settings';
        ln -s /usr/share/pipewire /etc/pipewire;
        touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio;
        systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager;
        systemctl --user start pulseaudio;
        show_solver_menu;;
     3) echo 'Package upgrade';
        apt update && apt upgrade -y;
        show_solver_menu;;
     4) show_root_menu;;
     x) echo 'Reboot';
        reboot;;
     q) clear; 
        exit ;;
esac

show_nvidia_menu
case "$result" in
     1) echo 'NVidia driver 515 installation';
        apt install nvidia-driver-515 -y;
        show_nvidia_menu;;
     2) echo 'NVidia driver 525 installation';
        apt install nvidia-driver-525 -y;
        show_nvidia_menu;;
     3) echo 'Package upgrade';
        apt update && apt upgrade -y;
        show_nvidia_menu;;
     4) show_root_menu;;
     x) echo 'Reboot';
        reboot;;
     q) clear; exit ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your installer, there are four menu calls `show_root_menu`, `show_pckg_menu`, `show_solver_menu` and `show_nvidia_menu`,
each followed the corresponsing case statement.

And this is what happens: When the root menu is shown and the user presses `cancel`, the package menu is shown. Press `cancel`-> solver menu, `cancel`-> nvidia menu, `cancel`-> exit (end of script).

If you start the script again and press `7` (nvidia menu), then press `4` to go back to the root menu, the case-statement is missing and `show_pckg_menu` is called instead.

The fix: Only call `show_root_menu` at the end of the script and move the case statements into their corresponding functions
after `result=$(dialog...)`.

```
#!/bin/bash
show_root_menu(){
width=72
height=50
menu_height=8
backtitle="Installer-menu"
title="Setup opions"
menu="Choose one of the following options:"

options=(1 'Add Mint PPA and update' 
         2 'Install Cinnamon '
         3 'update and upgrade '
         4 'Additional software installation '
         5 'Upgrade Kernel '
         6 'Resolve Ubuntu Cinnamon issues '
         7 'Install graphic proprietary driver'
         x reboot
         q quit )
    
result=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                --title "$title" \
                --menu "$menu" \
                $height $width $menu_height \
                "${options[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

case "$result" in
    1)  echo 'Mint backport repos installed';
        apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com A1715D88E1DF1F24 40976EAF437D05B5 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32 A6616109451BBBF2;
        sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.linuxmint.com vanessa main upstream import backport romeo" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list';
        sh -c 'echo "deb-src http://packages.linuxmint.com vanessa main upstream import backport romeo" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mint.list';
        apt-key export 451BBBF2 | gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mint.gpg;
        apt update;
        show_root_menu;;
    2)  echo 'Installation of Cinnamon';
        apt install slick-greeter muffin cinnamon;
        show_root_menu;;
    3)  echo 'Package upgrade';
        apt update && apt upgrade -y;
        show_root_menu;;
    4)  show_pckg_menu;;
    5)  sh ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh;
        show_root_menu;;
    6)  show_solver_menu;;
    7)  show_nvidia_menu;;
    x)  echo Reboot;
        reboot;;
    q)  clear; 
        exit ;;
esac
}
show_pckg_menu(){
width=72
height=22
menu_height=8
backtitle='Installer-menu'
title='Package options'
menu='Choose one of the following options:'

options=(1 'Install package list'
         2 'Export package list'
         3 'update and upgrade'
         4 'Show root menu'
         x reboot
         q quit )

result=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                --title "$title" \
                --menu "$menu" \
                $height $width $menu_height \
                "${options[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

case "$result" in
     1) echo 'Package Install';
        sh installpkgs.sh;;
     2) echo 'Manualy installed packages exported';
        sh pkgsexport.sh;;
     3) echo 'Package upgrade';
        apt update && apt upgrade -y;
        show_pckg_menu;;
     4) show_root_menu;;
     x) echo 'Reboot';
        reboot;;
     q) clear; 
        exit ;;
esac
}
show_solver_menu(){
width=72
height=22
menu_height=8
backtitle='Installer-menu'
title='Resolver menu'
menu='Choose one of the following options:'

options=(1 'Network applet problem'
         2 'Sound problem'
         3 'update and upgrade'
         4 'Show root menu'
         x reboot
         q quit )


result=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                --title "$title" \
                --menu "$menu" \
                $height $width $menu_height \
                "${options[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

case "$result" in
     1) echo 'Applying changes to network settings';
        clear;
        option_picked "Option 1 Picked";
        touch /etc/network/interfaces;
        sh -c 'echo "auto lo" >> /etc/network/interfaces';
        sh -c 'echo "iface lo inet loopback" >> /etc/network/interfaces';
        sh -c 'echo "  renderer: NetworkManager" >> /etc/netplan/*.yaml';
        netplan apply;
        show_solver_menu;;
     2) echo 'Applying changes to sound settings';
        ln -s /usr/share/pipewire /etc/pipewire;
        touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio;
        systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager;
        systemctl --user start pulseaudio;
        show_solver_menu;;
     3) echo 'Package upgrade';
        apt update && apt upgrade -y;
        show_solver_menu;;
     4) show_root_menu;;
     x) echo 'Reboot';
        reboot;;
     q) clear; 
        exit ;;
esac
}
show_nvidia_menu(){
width=72
height=22
menu_height=8
backtitle='Installer-menu'
title='NVidia driver selection'
menu='Choose one of the following options:'

options=(1 'Install nvidia 515'
         2 'Install nvidia 525'
         3 'Update and upgrade'
         4 'Show root menu'
         x reboot
         q quit )

result=$(dialog --clear \
                --backtitle "$backtitle" \
                --title "$title" \
                --menu "$menu" \
                $height $width $menu_height \
                "${options[@]}" \
                2>&1 >/dev/tty)

case "$result" in
     1) echo 'NVidia driver 515 installation';
        apt install nvidia-driver-515 -y;
        show_nvidia_menu;;
     2) echo 'NVidia driver 525 installation';
        apt install nvidia-driver-525 -y;
        show_nvidia_menu;;
     3) echo 'Package upgrade';
        apt update && apt upgrade -y;
        show_nvidia_menu;;
     4) show_root_menu;;
     x) echo 'Reboot';
        reboot;;
     q) clear; exit ;;
esac
}

show_root_menu
```

Comment: I did already changed the title on the repo and I've tried like you explained here, after the post of my question, but didn't stated the root value at the end. It gave an error. Thanks for the corrections made. I think I get it know. @Freddy